# How to use the index of a JavaScript loop in a thymeleaf iteration?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I would like to use the index of this JavaScript loop to iterate my thymeleaf integration. For example:

```
for(let i=1; i<8; i++){
    /*[# th:each="temp : ${arrayListTemperature[ i ] }"]*/
        {x: new Date[(${temp})]},
    /*[/]*/
}
```

To get

```
/*[# th:each="temp : ${arrayListTemperature1}"]*/
    { x: new Date[(${temp})]},
/*[/]*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thymeleaf is executed server-side, **before** the page is send to the browser.

Your JavaScript is executed client-side, **after** the page is send to the browser.

So what you're asking looks impossible: thymeleaf can't access a value during its execution, while this value will exist after thymeleaf was executed.